# Css design skills

Tags: css

I have seen this article: **[CSS3 Loading elements](http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-loading-elements/comment-page-1/#comment-18747)** at HTML5 and CSS3 Tutorials pages.

How did someone made this calculations? what angle, how much space, how much rotation to give?

If I do it with hand, starting number one, I fear it takes too long as a process to complete. 
Is there some tool, or some trick that do this or is it based on some technique that I am unaware somehow?

[EDIT] I am trying to tweak the width and height of this CSS, in order to make it smaller, and is broken. It seems to be calculated as is and you can't touch it.

Comment: It may help to leave a comment for the author at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Indeed goog idea, and I really did

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also, the sister site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/?as=1 may be a better place to move the question to.

Comment: Emmad, thank you too, is there abutton to move it, or delete and repost ?

Comment: I guess you click on "flag" to flag it to the site moderator's attention.

Comment: @Emmad: This isn't really a ux question, it's a programming question or a math question.  The UX decisions are already made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle / rotation: `360 / # of elements = angle`.

So, if you want an 8-sided (as is used by CSS code), use 45 degree angle increments.

The time calculations are just `(element number) * delay`, with delay being 0.13.

Hence, the animation duration is `1.04 (0.13 * 8)` and each element's delay is 0.13 higher than the previous one.

Comment: @gnat, thanks! that gives transparency to the problem. But then changing the width or the height, outputs trash. Is there a division again between the width of the surface and the elements perhaps? What book should I look for to dig into these effects? For example from this snippet of code, the third element, is more advanced technique I think, somehow...I am totally newbie into css3 and html5 you see..

Comment: If you are going to change width and height of the elements, you should make the changes proportionally.  That is, multiply all the width, height, left, top, and transform:scale properties by the same factor.  Actually, you probably would only need to modify top, left, and transform:scale.  As for the top and left positions, I'm not completely sure how they are calculated.  I would have expected them to be calculated via trigonometry (sine and cosine), but the numbers don't match my expectations, so I'm missing a step.  As an aside, that CSS won't work in IE9.

Comment: As an aside, I recommend using a tool like Opera DragonFly or Firefox Firebug to make live-edits to your css.  It's significantly easier to get a feel for what your css is doing that way.

Comment: Indeed, I use firebug, all the time. You mention that in IE9, it won't work. How's that? why ? And if I am not that opressing guy, I need this thing to work for ie above 6 perhaps...[yes I know it's html5, so I just wanted to play with it] , could you suggest some alternative to look for ?

Comment: I opened it in IE9 and it failed.  [When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation) says not to expect CSS3 animation in IE9.  IE8 doesn't even have rotate (you can fake it with Matrix filters, but in my experience the results tend to look a little bit off).  For production use, I recommend just using an animated gif.

Comment: to tell you the truth, never tried on ie9. just a quick show up in firefox, and chrome. Nevertheless, thank you Brian for the effort of explaining.